# Pivotal Cedar Swift 3.0 compatibility

Tags: cedar-bdd

I have converted my app code from swift 2.0 to 3.0.
I have Pivotal cedar framework in the app which I used for TDD.
My app code is converted properly to swift 3.0, but not the test case code. 
Is Pivotal Cedar compatible with Swift 3.0?

Kaustubh

Comment: Is Pivotal Cedar coded in Objective C?

Comment: Yes, its coded in Objective c.

Comment: So, It should be compatible with Swift 3.0.